# Identifying the name of the application pool from a request

Tags: asp.net, .net, application-pool

In .net, in a webservice (or website) is there an easy way of getting the name of the application pool that the service is running in, from a `HttpRequest` or the `HttpContext`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the application pool name for a specific website IIS6 programaticaly? C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511263/how-to-get-the-application-pool-name-for-a-specific-website-iis6-programaticaly)

Comment: See [Playing around with IIS Application Pool using C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/robinkedia/archive/2009/04/28/playing-around-with-iis-application-pool-using-c.aspx), On SO - [Application Pool from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/application-pool-from-c-sharp)

Comment: not really - since the above would only apply to IIS and neither a webservice not a website would necessarily run in IIS...

Comment: This question was specific to IIS, so I can investigate Directory Services. It would be nice if I was able to just pluck it off the `HttpRequest`, but I suppose one can't expect everything to be simple.

Comment: You also don't want to rely on the permissions needed from a running site (what your site runs as) to demand admin permissions via DirectoryServices over IIS.  Your site should not run as admin.  Don't go there...

Answer (score 0):

I think its:

```
HttpRequest.ServerVariables["APP_POOL_ID"]
```

See ServerVariables on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx