# Get Application Pool Uptime in c#

Tags: c#, iis-7, application-pool

Is there a way I can determine how long an application pool (in IIS7) has been up (time since started, or last restart) in c#?

Comment: Externally, or within your ASP.NET app?

Comment: Externally. I've been playing around with the Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool, but I don't see anything as far as time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really stupid trick: in some class that everything uses, use a class constructor to remember your start time and use an aspx page to receive it. Now compare to current time.

Comment: By class constructor do you mean `static` constructor? Because the static constructor is what you'd want to do with this, I've never considered how easily you could use a static constructor to achieve something like this before though.

Comment: Yeah class constructor in IL = static constructor in C#.

Comment: The AppDomain can be recycled (change web.config) without the app pool being recycled (w3wp.exe process).  This static constructor will only measure latest appdomain restart.  Use process info answers (@EricHumphrey) if you really need the app pool process start time.

Comment: True, but I found when asking this question, the AppDomain is almost always what you want.

Answer (score 9):

```
DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
```

`Process.GetCurrentProcessInfo()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Interestingly, this survives an application restart, so I'm not sure how accurate this is.

Comment: This gets the start time of the w3wp process ( IIS Service ) and not the application pool.

Answer (score 3):

From the ASP.NET application, you can try `TimeSpan uptime = (DateTime.Now - ProcessInfo.GetCurrentProcessInfo ().StartTime)`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above I created a simple class like so..

```
public static class UptimeMonitor
{
    static DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    static UptimeMonitor()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public static int UpTimeSeconds
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Round((DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalSeconds,0); }
    }
}
```

and called it in Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs like

```
var temp = UptimeMonitor.UpTimeSeconds;
```

It can then be accessed anywhere using

```
UptimeMonitor.UpTimeSeconds
```

Answer (score 2):

if you find that Process.GetCurrentProcessInfo() doesn't exist as another user mentioned,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
```

may work for you.

(I wanted to add this as a comment to Eric Humphrey's post but I'm not allowed)

Answer (score 1):

One of two approaches exist that I personally use. Using a static class (as shown in @Original10's answer) or using `Application` variables.

I have found that using `Application` variables is acceptable because I noticed [`Process.GetCurrentProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess) survives application restarts (eg modification of web.config or bin directory). I needed something that would cater for the website restarting *as well*.

In your Global.asax, add the following to the `Application_Start` - and add the method it if it's not there.

```
public void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  Application["ApplicationStartTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
}
```

In your code where you need it, you could do something like:

```
var appStartTime = DateTime.MinValue;
var appStartTimeValue = Web.HttpCurrent.Application["ApplicationStartTime"].ToString();

DateTime.TryParseExact(appStartTimeValue, "o", null, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Out appStartTime);
var uptime = (DateTime.Now - appStartTime).TotalSeconds

var lsOutput = $"Application has been running since {appStartTime:o} - {uptime:n0} seconds."
```

Which will produce something along the lines of

```
Application has been running since 2018-02-16T10:00:56.4370974+00:00 - 10,166 seconds.
```

There is no checking of the application variable or locking of the application if required. I'll leave this as an exercise to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you mashed [Restarting (Recycling) an Application Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/application-pool-from-c) and http://forums.iis.net/t/1162615.aspx, you should get it