# Reload web.config after updating connectionstring programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have created Connectionstring in web.config at run time. Now I am saving some data into my DB but it is still reading old Connectionstring. How can I solve this? below is my code:

```
public string EditConnectionString(string userId, string password, string host, string dbName)
{
    try
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration Config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        ConnectionStringsSection conSetting = (ConnectionStringsSection)Config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        string providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        string conString = @"metadata=res://*/OWordpress.csdl|res://*/OWordpress.ssdl|res://*/OWordpress.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=" + "\"data source=" + host + ";initial catalog=" + dbName + ";user id=" + userId + ";password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\"";
        ConnectionStringSettings StringSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings("OWordpressContainer", conString,providerName);
        conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Remove(StringSettings);
        conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Add(StringSettings);
        Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        return MessageFamily.Success.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

After creating Connectionstring I am saving some data as below but it still read old connectionstring values:

```
public string SaveDbInfo(string userId, string password, string host, string dbName)
{
    try
    {
        var optionEntity = new Options();

        optionEntity.key = "DBInfo";
        optionEntity.value = "{userId:'" + userId + "',password:'" + password + "',host:'"+host+"',dbName:'"+dbName+"'}";

        objContext.Options.Add(optionEntity);
        objContext.SaveChanges();
        return MessageFamily.Success.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: After changing the connection string, when old connection string is being used, is your values getting saved properly?

Comment: yes It is getting saved in web.config file

Comment: How and *where* did you save the changes? Modifying a web application's `web.config` causes the application to restart

Comment: If you're changing the ConnectionString at runtime why save it in the web.config at all? You can pass the whole connectionstring into the DbContext constructor without it being a named connection in web.config.

Comment: Did your code actually work, or did it result in an exception without saving? Did you check the return value of `EditConnectionString` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue by using `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`

```
var ecsBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OWordpressContainer"].ToString());

var sqlCsBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ecsBuilder.ProviderConnectionString)
{
    InitialCatalog = dbName,
    UserID=userId,
    DataSource=host,
    Password=password
};

var providerConnectionString = sqlCsBuilder.ToString();                
ecsBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerConnectionString;    
string contextConnectionString = ecsBuilder.ToString();   

using (var db = new DbContext(contextConnectionString))
{
    OWordpressContainer objContext = new OWordpressContainer(contextConnectionString);    
    var optionEntity = new Options();    
    optionEntity.key = "DBInfo";    
    optionEntity.value = "{userId:" + userId + "',password:'" + password + "',host:'" + host + "',dbName:'" + dbName + "'}";    
    objContext.Options.Add(optionEntity);    
    objContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This isn't saving anything. If all you wanted was to connect to a different database, why were you asking about saving connection strings?

Comment: I think he wanted to connect to different database using same DBContext of EntityFramework and ConnectionName but different Database having same schema but doing it dynamic and on the fly. The answer seems to be good solving his purpose.

Comment: This code has issues - it opens two DbContexts, closes the unused one and leaves `OWordpressContainer` open

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code after you are changing the connection string and let me know if it helped or not-

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Comment: Ohk, did you added this line after - Config.Save() ?

Comment: yes  I did after Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

Comment: You can try recycling the app pool after you make the changes in the web.config, using this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/249942/3748701. NOTE: this will erase all the server session data, try this for testing purposes first, then let me know what happened.

Comment: Then I don't know my friend, how to help you, in one of my project I did the same thing and had used ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection which had worked perfectly :)

Comment: None of this helps because modifying `web.config` forces an application restart anyway. If the changes were actually saved, the application would have restarted with the new settings