# How to get name of current IIS app pool programatically, not ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api2, application-pool

I am running into a situation with my `Web API` where the only option I can think of right now is to `recycle` the `app pool` while I dig through and find out the real cause of the problem. In the mean time I need a way to `recycle` the `app pool` after a condition is met. I thought I found the solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780076/Recycle-Application-Pool-s-in-IIS-Server-Using-C

```
// Needs Microsoft.Web.Administration NuGet
public static void RecycleAppPool()
{
    ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
    ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["Test_AppPool"];

    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
        {
            appPool.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            appPool.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1) I am getting an error when trying to run this code: "Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions" I am getting this error in localhost, but I assume I'll also get it in my hosted `Azure` environment? Can I get around this?

2) The second problem is I may not know what the name of the app pool is, so I need to figure that out programatically. I've found something like this:http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2008/02/find-and-recycle-current-application-pool-programmatically-for-iis-6/ but that uses `ActiveDirectory` and I will not have the login details for the `AD` at my host... at least not that I know of... again this is hosted in an Azure Website.

So the question is, how do I get the name and of the current app pool in `Azure` and recycle it?

As a side note, I'm doing this in my `Global.asax` in the `Application_EndRequest` after `Flush`ing the current `Response`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you attempting to use MWA in an Azure Web app?

Comment: I guess yes? I'm just trying to get this to work...

Comment: Azure web apps attempt to hide the back end infrastructure from you so I don't think they give you access to all MWA API access (and they shouldn't as your calls might break others' apps).

Comment: Ok, so how do I restart my own app pool?

Comment: why do you need to recycle the pool? That's the real problem you want to solve, right?

Comment: Yes, but I may not be able to track the real problem for who knows how long because it is intermittent, so in the mean time I need to recycle the app pool so the API stays alive...

Answer (score 0):

So far the closest I could find is (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1081902/550975)

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

which just restarts the `app`, not the `app pool`. This may however serve my purposes... we'll see. I'm still hoping someone has the actual answer, and I will mark it as the Accepted Answer if such a thing ever occurs.