# Possible to mimic web.config restart behaviour for my own config files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

When you modify the "web.config" file of an ASP.NET (MVC) application, [the application is automatically recompiled/restarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228058.aspx), forcing the modified "web.config" to be read-in.

**My question:**

Is it possible to apply this change-detection behaviour for my own configuration files (let's say "my-config.json") in the root of an ASP.NET website?

I.e. when someone modifies the "my-config.json" file, the application gets restarted.

Comment: You can have a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)  to watch your files and detect changes and then restart application.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Nice idea. It seems that there are only [undocumented ways](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/04/how-to-restart-iis-worker-process.html) to restart an ASP.NET application?

Comment: There are some answers in SO about restarting the application, for example: [Restarting (Recycling) an Application Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/restarting-recycling-an-application-pool), Also you can restart using

Comment: Maybe you don't need to restart the application, and you only need to reload your settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)  to watch your files and detect changes and then restart application or reload your settings.

Maybe you don't need to restart the application, and you only need to reload your settings

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Other initializations ...
    // ....

    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    //Set the folder to watch
    watcher.Path = Server.MapPath("~/Config");
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    //Set a filter to watch
    watcher.Filter = "*.json";
    watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Restart application here
    //Or Reload your settings
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!