# where is ServerManagerDemoGlobals class in c# with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

i am using following code snippet to restart IIS [IIS with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/restarting-recycling-an-application-pool)

But i am not finding `ServerManagerDemoGlobals`  .I added both dll `Microsoft.Web.Management.dll and Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` ,but still not able find it

Comment: any idea about ServerManagerDemoGlobals ??

Comment: I used following link [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/restarting-recycling-an-application-pool?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need this type. You can delete the

```
PropertyBag applicationPoolBag = new PropertyBag();
        applicationPoolBag[ServerManagerDemoGlobals.ApplicationPoolArray] = applicationPool;
        arrayOfApplicationBags.Add(applicationPoolBag);
```

lines all together and the code will still accomplish the application restart you're trying to achieve.