# how to make iis, re compile project when source changes

Tags: c#, iis

Is there any solution to make **IIS** recompile the project, if some changes were happen in the source on run time? I'm using **c#-CodeDOM** and I'm generating some classes **run time**. So, I need recompile project for updating my new **dll** s information.

Comment: You could simply recycle the apppool: http://stackoverflow.com/a/249942/578411

Comment: this source which you sent was not useful to me ...i think it just work with .net2 @rene...it has some think like PropertyBag which i didnt find any dll about that

Comment: sure, but that question has many answers you could try. The second best there offers `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` which could work for you, assuming your website is configured to do an auto restart. Above all you didn't specify for which IIS version or .NET runtime you need an solution. I assume .NET 2.0 stuff will work in newer runtimes as well.