# Ho Do I Restart Sitecore Server From Code?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

We have a requirement to install Sitecore packages programmatically from a custom admin page. The package installation is working but once the package is installed I wanted to restart the Sitecore server from code.

```
Sitecore.Install.Installer installer = new Sitecore.Install.Installer();
```

I tried with  installer.ExecutePostStep but not sure what action I need to provide to this function.
If anyone has done it before Please help .

Basically I wanted to execute the functionality from code what the two below check boxes are doing when we do manual installation.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249927/restarting-recycling-an-application-pool

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Marek Musielak.  I found that Sitecore installer class has many static method and there is one method to restart the server. Sitecore.Install.Installer.RestartServer();. I am yet to to test but this should work I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing will be to restart the Sitecore's application pool by a `Restart-Application` PowerShell command.

Find more details [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/restart-application).